# Python 3.3 Beginner: Need help understand how the "and not" part of this code functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say the user enters the integer 10. I know the print(the_sum) line produces 12 because 3 and 9 are both chosen. I don't understand why it is 3 and 9 that are chosen. In the if statement line: "number % 2 and not number % 3" is where I am getting confused. I guess I just don't understand what the "and not" is doing to change that line to produce 3 and 9 to be added for the_sum. Any help would be greatly appreciated so I can move forward with more understanding.

```
the_max = int(input("Enter the upper limit:"))
the_sum = 0
extra = 0

for number in range(1,the_max):
    if number%2 and not number%3:
        the_sum = the_sum + number
    else:
        extra += 1 

print(the_sum) 
print(extra)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if number%2 and not number%3:
```

To understand this line you first have to understand how ints are treated when used in a bool context. In a nutshell, any int that has a value of `0` is considered `False` and all other ints are considered `True`.

Now, when is `n % 2` equal to `0` so as to be considered `False`? Well, when `n` is evenly divisible by 2. The same can be said for `n % 3`: it's `False` when `n` is evenly divisible by 3. So that if-statement can be thought of as:

```
If ((number is not divisible by 2) and (number is divisible by 3))
```

Note that since `n % 3` is true for all ints not divisible by 3, `not n % 3` is true for all ints that *are* divisible by 3.

This matches the output you see: `9` and `3` are the only two integers in the range 1 to 9 (inclusive) that satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the components for 9:

```
>>> 9 % 2
1
>>> 9 % 3
0
>>> not 9 % 3
True
>>> 9 % 2 and not 9 % 3
True
```

Numeric 0 is false in a boolean context, and any *other* number is considered true. `not 0` is therefor *true*.

For any other number, the combination never returns true values for both tests:

```
>>> 1 % 2
1
>>> 1 % 3
1
>>> not 1 % 3
False
```

In other words, only numbers that are **not** divisible by 2 but **are** divisible by 3 are picked.

To simplify understanding, you could explicitly test for numeric 0 instead:

```
if number % 2 != 0 and number % 3 == 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator (`%`) will return an int, which corresponds to the remainder of division of the 2 numbers. In `if` statements, Python treats numbers according to their truthiness -- `0` is falsey, everything else is truthy. So this code is being a little bit too clever. I would clarify it like so:

```
    if number % 2 != 0 and number % 3 == 0:
```